# where does one define the creation of the database in the new Visual Studio Database project

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I see that I can "Create a deployment Script and deploy the database" as a deployment action, howerver it's not clear where I script the actual creation of the database?  I see under the "Storage" folder a sub folder for Filegroups, Files, and I'm guessing I could drop in a create database script into there, but how do I pick up the database name (which is set as a project property)

Perhaps a better question would be where is this well documented?

Answer (score 0):

The Deploy Action that you see in a VS2010 Database Project Properties will take place when you deploy, which you do either by selecting the Deploy Solution option in the Build menu, or by right clicking on the project in the Solution Explorer.

The name that is used is the Target Database Name, which is set in the same screen.

You don't need to drop the create script anywhere. This is generated for you. If you select the "Create a deployment script and deploy to the database", it is also applied for you.

Comment: The issue is I need to script the files and filegroups for the database,( including things like initial and max size, location etc)